# When exporting a project in eclipse, Some tasks in Task View are not copied with it

Tags: eclipse, project, task

When exporting then importing a java project in eclipse, Some tasks are not ported in the imported project.
These are the tasks that were created by right click on the editor Markers area and "Add Task".

How to force eclipse to export those tasks too with the project ??

Comment: Aren't your tasks synchronized with a repository?

Comment: I was asking the "Tasks View" not the "Tasks List".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task annotation is a so called [marker](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_markers.htm). While markers in Eclipse are associated with resources in projects, they are *not contained in projects*. Therefore you cannot import or export them together with a project. Markers are stored in the meta data of the workspace only, therefore an exported project (outside of a workspace) *cannot* contain persisted markers.

If you now ask: Why are my TODO, FIXME and XXX markers still available after export and import? This is because those are always just parsed from the Java code, and are not stored separately as marker, therefore after import they can be parsed again.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO its not possible to export these type of tasks using File->Export wizard. Reason might be any task is associated with the line number and with the file path. If you import the projects or tasks on some other workspace then file paths may change.

However you can export **Task View Configuration** by using File->Export wizard. Select Preferences then select Task View Configuration.